# Passing a reference to an offset position in an STL vector

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to convert some old C functions to C++. My original programme stores a matrix in a single array, and I just pass a pointer to the first element to a function so that I am working on the correct row, e.g.

```
double f1(int *a){
 return a[0] + a[1];
}

int main(void){
  int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  printf("%d\n", f1(&x[2 * i]));
}
```

I would like to be able to do something similar using the STL **without** copying. So my programme would look something like this

```
double f1(vector<int>& a){
 return a[0] + a[1];
}
int main(void){
  int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  vector<int> y(x, x + 10);

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     cout << f1(y) << endl; // This is clearly wrong
}
```

How would I do this? I could change my function to receive a reference to a vector::iterator I guess, but is there another way?

Comment: What is the problem with passing an iterator?

Comment: It's very dangerous to make pointers to stl containers, they have every right to move data around without telling you. In the case of this simple print you can access the data using x[i] ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/)) which will return a reference to the contained element. Is your intended use more complicated and dependant on using references?

Comment: An iterator is the natural solution, and isn't obviously more expensive to pass than a pointer. Equally, vector is deliberately specified so that you can just use pointers if you really prefer (in this case, with no invalidation etc. etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply pass an iterator to the function. Random access iterators are very similar to pointers (in fact, pointers qualify as random access iterators.) For example,

```
#include <vector>

double f1(std::vector<int>::const_iterator a)
{
    return a[0] + a[1];
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  vector<int> y{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  auto it = y.cbegin();

  for(int i = 0; i < y.size()/2; ++i)
      std::cout << f1(it + 2*i) <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When `a` is an iterator, can you access the correct vector elements using `a[0]` and `a[1]` like that? Rather than something like `*a` and `*(a+1)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau For a [**random access iterator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), yes.

Answer (score 2):

Write array view.  An array view is a pair of pointers with `begin` `end` `size` `empty`, `operator[]`, `front` and `back` methods, and constructors from C arrays, `std::array<T,N>&`, `std::vector<T,A>&`, `std::vector<non_const_T,A>const&`, `std::array<non_const_T,N>const&`, `std::initializer_list<non_const_T>`, etc.

Oh, and `T*,size_t` and `T*,T*` ctors, which are great for slicing (use forwarding ctors: `T*,size_t`->`T*,T*`, and everything else to those 2).

It does not own its data, so all of its methods are `const` except `operator=`.  (non-`const` methods would be methods that change the view range -- changing the elements is a `const` operation on a view).

Then

```
double f1(array_view<const int> a){
  return a[0] + a[1];
}
```

Comment: I like this solution and will probably implement it in time. However, I think the iterator approach might be the easiest in a short amount of time

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make so many changes:

```
double f1(int *a)
{
     return a[0] + a[1];
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << f1(&y[2 * i]) << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid pointers. It's not that I don't know how to use them - just seeing what I can do without them.

Comment: @user46833 `vector::iterator` still has all the same semantics as a pointer, except that it makes your function less useful because your function will only be usable with a vector.   If you want to broaden your horizons, change `f1` to take a `ForwardIterator` template parameter. However `main` still does not need to change anything, `&y[2*i]` satisfies the iterator requirements.